# Почему GET запрос не попадает в метод с аннотацией @GetMapping с параметрами в Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Имеется метод в контроллере, который обрабатывает GET запрос. Данный метод помечен аннотацией `@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY, ParameterName.SORT_TYPE})`. У данного метода в аргументах с помощью аннотации `@RequestParam` идет привязка аргумента, пришедшего из GET запроса к переменной Java типа String. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```java
@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY, ParameterName.SORT_TYPE})
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAllAndSort(@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_BY) String sortBy,
                                                @RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_TYPE, required = false) String sortType) {
        log.info("Sorting: {}, {}", sortBy, sortType);

        return service.findAllAndSort(sortType, sortBy);
    }
```

У аргумента `sortType` стоит `required = false`, что означает, что данный аргумент **не обязательно должен присутствовать**: `@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_TYPE, required = false) String sortType)`.

В исходниках написано:

> The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.
> Same format for any environment: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style expressions, with a request only mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value. Expressions can be negated by using the "!=" operator, as in "myParam!=myValue". "myParam" style expressions are also supported, with such parameters having to be present in the request (allowed to have any value). Finally, "!myParam" style expressions indicate that the specified parameter is not supposed to be present in the request.
> Supported at the type level as well as at the method level! When used at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this parameter restriction.

Что значит, что все параметны, указанные в `@GetMapping(params = {...})` должны присутствовать в запросе. Тогда зачем делать флаг `required` в `@RequestParam`?

Тогда вопрос, почему при запросе вида:

1. `http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_by=name&sort_type=DESC`
   запрос **попадает** в данный метод.
2. `http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_by=name`
   **не попадает** в данный метод

**UPDATE**
@roman-konoval
Если аннотации работат на разных этапах, почему тогда такой вариант не работает?

````java
@GetMapping
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAllAndSort(@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_BY) String sortBy,
                                                @RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_TYPE, required = false) String sortType) {
        log.info("Sorting: {}, {}", sortBy, sortType);
        
return service.findAllAndSort(sortType, sortBy);
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Аннотации работают на разных этапах и независимо друг от друга. На разных этапах: `GetMapping` при выборе метода-обработчика, а `RequestParam` при преобразовании аргументов для метода обработчика. Независимо: `RequestParam` можно использовать и без `GetMapping`, а с другими способами задания метода для обработки запроса, которые сами не умеют и никак не используют информацию о пришедших параметрах.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, я для чего это создавал? Ситуация в следующем. Мне нужно принять массив параметров из GET запроса `sort_by`. Правильно ли я это делаю (добавил в топик)?

Comment: Что касается нескольких значений, то я не уверен, что можно использовать vararg (никогда не пробовал), если использовать `List<String>`, то будет работать. Касательно update2. Во-первых, не ясно, что именно значит "не работает". Какой url используете и что в результате получаете? Во-вторых, неясно, что еще в контроллере есть, какой мапинг на классе и какие другие мапинги есть.

Comment: просто поменяй String sortType на Optional<String> sortType и не нужно required=false, spring и так поймет

Comment: @GlebKuznetsov, хм, интересное решение. Но если аннотировать `@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY, ParameterName.SORT_TYPE})` и не указать `sort_type`, то всё равно не попадет запрос в метод.

Comment: @Jake ну так убери params. Оно никакой полезной нагрузки не несет. Если тебе для документации API, swagger или spring docs и так все сгеренируют как надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опишу ход эксперимента, чтобы другим было полезнее.

Сначала я пробовал составить запрос вида:

```xml
http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_by=[name,description]
```

Но квадратные скобки ``` [``] ``` не поддерживаются, так как допустимые симолы GET запроса определены в стандарте RFC 7230 and RFC 3986.

В итоге пришёл к решения сделать два метода и заменил в аргументе `String ... sortBy` на `Set<String> sortBy`. Теперь GET запрос выглядит:

```xml
http://localhost:8080/gift-certificates?sort_by=name&sort_by=description
```

```java
@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY})
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAllAndSort(@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_BY) Set<String> sortBy) {
        log.info("Sorting 1: {}", sortBy);

        return service.findAllAndSort(sortType, sortBy);
    }

@GetMapping(params = {ParameterName.SORT_BY, ParameterName.SORT_TYPE})
    public List<GiftCertificate> findAllAndSortWithSortType(@RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_BY) Set<String> sortBy,
                                                            @RequestParam(value = ParameterName.SORT_TYPE) String sortType) {
        log.info("Sorting 2: {}, {}", sortBy, sortType);

        return service.findAllAndSort(sortType, sortBy);
    }
```

Но вопрос организации данной ситуации с помощью одного метода остается открытым.